# Повторный прогон программы

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать повторный прогон алгоритмов без запуска программы (хотите начать заново? (y/n)). На примере простейшей программы "Hello, world".

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   std::cout<<"Hello, world!\n";
}
```

Comment: Когда-то давным-давно люди придумали  для этого циклы

Comment: можно пример?

Comment: @siner откройте любую книжку по C++

Comment: @siner: и правда, вы бы книгу почитали. Спойлер: можете прокрутить сразу к циклу `while` (хотя я бы порекомендовал прочитать всё).

Answer (score 1):

Есть два пути:

1. заключается в том, чтобы весь код программы поместить в цикл `while`. И добавить булевую переменную, для проверки (нужно ли повторять программу).
2. функция `main` запускает функцию в которой будет основной код программы, в конце этой функции будет стоять оператор `if`, который будет запускать заново функцию с основным кодом программы (данный путь не оптимален для многочисленного повтора).